# Firebase functions:log - HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials

Tags: firebase

I issued the command "firebase functions:log" from the command line and received the error:

```
Error: Failed to list log entries HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

I am logged in to firebase, since the command "firebase login" responds with:

```
Already logged in as [my email address]
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I logged out of firebase on the command line via "firebase logout", then logged backed in via "firebase login" to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I logged out of firebase on the command line via "firebase logout", then logged backed in via "firebase login" to resolve the issue